# Can the excessive consumption of mineral water lead to kidney stones or other health issues?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, kidney

I heard that drinking too much mineral (bottled) water could lead to problems such as kidney stones because of the high amount of minerals in it. Is it true? If so, what is considered to be excessive?

Answer (score 3):

I suffer from calcium oxalate stones.  My doctor pointed me to this study:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9096270

tl;dr;  For calcium oxalate, drinking Mineral Water high in Calcium and Magnesium may reduce the risk of forming stones.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that drinking too much mineral water will cause kidney stones. One of the chief causes of kidney stones is dehydration. I can't imagine the calcium content of mineral water could be that high as to cause kidney stones (please correct me if I'm wrong) unless you drink ridiculous amount by which stage you will probably start to have electrolyte abnormalities and perhaps seizures.

Consumption of excessive amount of water can cause various health issues (even life threatening). These include seizures, rhythm disturbances in the heart (all usually secondary to acute electrolyte imbalance in the blood).

I've never come across drinking too much mineral water as a cause for kidney stones-most people who get kidney stones usually aren't drinking enough water. The more water you take (in moderation), the less the likelihood for stone formation in your kidneys.